# Cannot export and pass virtual fields in MongoDB under mongoose module to Handlebars in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

I'm following a Node.JS tutorial on the internet about Node.JS, Handlebars and Mongoogse with MongoDB.
[YouTube Tutorial](https://youtu.be/TqC3e8nBycg?t=7244)
When we create the model, adding extra virtual fields afterwards do not propagate (or are passed) to the handlebars page. The rest of the native dabatase fields do work.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const path = require('path');
const ImageSchema = new Schema ({
    title: { type: String },
    description: { type: String },
    filename: { type: String },
    views: { type: Number, default: 0},
    likes: { type: Number, default: 0},
    timeStamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
},{
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
}
);
ImageSchema.virtual('uniqueId').get(function () { //dato que generamos virtualmente para tener el nombre del archivo de la imagen sin la extensión
    return this.filename.replace(path.extname(this.filename), '');
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Image', ImageSchema);
```

On the receiving end (hbs file), the following happens:

```
<h6>uniqueId: {{uniqueId}}</h6> {{!-- does not work --}}
<h6>Archivo: {{filename}}</h6> {{!-- works --}}
```

I tried adding both toObject and toJSON with no luck :-(

```
const ImageSchema = new Schema ({
    title: { type: String },
    description: { type: String },
    filename: { type: String },
    views: { type: Number, default: 0},
    likes: { type: Number, default: 0},
    timeStamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
},{
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
}
);
```

Thanks for your great help in advance.